# syntax to use a constant in parenthesis of add (new DateInterval('')) command

Tags: php, syntax, constants

I have a constant to syncronize the MYSQL server hour with my country's hour.

in `add(new DateInterval('PT3H'))` command, **instead of 3** I want to use my constant.

I ask for the correct syntax. I tried `{MY_CONSTANT}` however I got `Unknown or bad format error` message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use string concatenation: `'PT'.MY_CONSTANT.'H'`. `{MY_CONSTANT}` does not work, because there is no `{$` sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
add(new DateInterval('PT'.MY_CONSTANT.'H'))
```

Answer (score 0):

In a case if you just do not like concat operator `.`, you may use [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/sprintf) function:

```
add(new DateInterval(sprintf('PT%dH', MY_CONSTANT)));
```

Where `%d` is a placeholder for an integer value.